# How do I set up YubiKey 2FA on GitHub without a phone?

Tags: github, yubico

I have no smartphone and I only carry my cheap dumbphone when I know I might actually need it to contact someone (ie. approximately never). Generally speaking, I have no phone I'd use as a trusted device.

I *do* have a YubiKey Neo and a laptop.

GitHub's 2FA appears to require a trusted SMS-capable phone in order to even start configuring it.

- Is there any way to bypass this requirement?
- Is there a good reason for this requirement? 'Everyone has one' is, as already indicated, not a good reason.

Comment: `Is there a good reason for this requirement? 'Everyone has one' is, as already indicated, not a good reason.` Everyone they care about being able to access their product has one?

Comment: That's a good reason, yes. :P Still very irritating... vaguely interested in whether it's a conscious business decision or a mere assumption. I consider the former acceptable, but the latter reprehensible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-two-factor-authentication-via-fido-u2f/), "You must have already configured 2FA via a TOTP mobile app or via SMS," in order to configure FIDO (YubiKey's standard) 2FA.